# Given component holder class androidx.compose.ui.tooling.PreviewActivity does not implement interface dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponent

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel, dagger-hilt, illegalstateexception

**After update some library in Jetpack Compose, I got this issue when run preview**

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Given component holder class androidx.compose.ui.tooling.PreviewActivity does not implement interface dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponent or interface dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponentManager
at dagger.hilt.EntryPoints.get(EntryPoints.java:62)
at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.createInternal(HiltViewModelFactory.java:149)
at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.createInternal(HiltViewModelFactory.java:143)

My Screen PreView :

```kotlin
@Preview
@Composable
fun CatalogOverviewScreenPreview() {
    JetpackComposeCatalogTheme {
        CatalogOverviewRoute({})
    }
}
```

My screen with hilt ViewModel :

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CatalogOverviewRoute(
    navigateCatalogDetail: (CatalogComposeEnum) -> Unit,
    viewModel: CatalogOverviewViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val catalogList by viewModel.catalogOverViewGroupList.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    CatalogOverviewScreen(catalogList, navigateCatalogDetail, viewModel::updateExpand)
}
```

Did anyone get this issue after update version compose library and how you guys fixed it ? Thank a lot

I want to preview normally without issue

Comment: You are passing ViewModel is passed as a parameter so that Preview will not be generated. You can Pass State As Parameter To Make Your Preview work.